# (DUAL BOOT) Windows 10 crash randomly in my dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, google-chrome

In my dual boot setup, Windows 10 that previously installed when I bought the laptop is crash randomly. Sometimes about one hour since the laptop boot into Windows 10, sometimes it's when I about Google Chrome, sometimes It's when I started to open multiple applications. Previously, the crash is worse, after login into Windows 10, the Windows 10 freeze and then crashed after I open any program. Then, I turned off fast startup. The windows seems stable for a period of time, but since 2 days ago the Windows still crash randomly. Here's the common error that I encountered in Windows 10 since I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 in my laptop :

1. Internet browser (Google Chrome and Firefox) when I open the application.
2. Video dxgkrnl fatal error
3. Microsoft Teams close and reopen for multiple of times, after I open another application, i.e Whatsapp for dekstop.
4. Sometimes I can't login to Steam from Steam client.

What I already tried :

1. Update the windows
2. In device management, uninstall devices for NVIDIA GPU under display driver, then install the driver again
3. Reinstall Whatsapp for Desktop, Steam, Microsoft Teams, Google Chrome, and Mozilla Firefox

Here's my Setup :

1. Laptop : MSI GF63 THIN 9SCR
2. GPU : Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q Design
3. Dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04)
4. Fast startup disabled in Windows 10
5. In GNU GRUB screen, the text displayed is 'Windows Boot Manager' not 'Windows 10'

Before dual booting, the Windows 10 works fine. After dual booting, the Windows 10 crashed randomly and Ubuntu 20.04 works fine. What can I do to fix my Windows 10? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Start with the obvious things: Updates drivers, Intel, Nvidia, etc. Check for malware/virus. Check the drive's health. Keep Fast Startup disabled, a MUST when dual-booting but even so avoid writing to the Windows system partition from Ubuntu. Having a separated NTFS data partition shared between the OSes is fine.

Comment: Update October 14th 2021,one day after I asked this question, I decided to reset my windows 10. Since I don't have many important files in the Windows 10, I decided to do a 'clean' reset without keeping any files. Now both Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 works fine in my laptop.